# How to pass variable to double metaphone function

Tags: python

I've downloaded the double metaphone function: https://github.com/dracos/double-metaphone

It' supposed to work like this:

```
>>> dm(u'aubrey')
('APR', '')
>>> dm(u'richard')
('RXRT', 'RKRT')
>>> dm(u'katherine') == dm(u'catherine')
True
```

How do I pass a variable to this function? The u is always in the way. I need to be able to do

```
dm(x)==dm(y)
```

right now this is what happens:

```
>>> x='wal mart'
>>> y='wall mart'
>>> dm(x)==dm(y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
dm(x)==dm(y)
File "<pyshell#18>", line 6, in dm
st = ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', st) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))
TypeError: normalize() argument 2 must be unicode, not str
```

Comment: That should work. What's the problem exactly? Also the `u''` syntax means 'unicode'.

Comment: The `u` prefix is just to indicate the string should be interpreted as a unicode literal in Python 2.x. It's not "getting in the way" of anything...

Comment: when you do a 'dm(x)==dm(y)' it throws an error. I've edited the answer above to show the error

Comment: @fredykruger it looks like the `dm()` function expects unicode. just define `x` and `y` as unicode: `x=u'wal mart'` and it should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`u''` is the syntax for a literal `unicode` string object, comparable to a regular `str` object except that it can handle Unicode characters.

```
>>> type('foobar')
<type 'str'>
>>> type(u'foobar')
<type 'unicode'>
>>> 'foobar' == u'foobar'
True
```

As long as your input is accepted by the function you're calling, you don't need the `u`.  For example:

```
x = u'richard'
dm(x)
```

---

You receive TypeError because the function expects `unicode` objects and you are passing it `str` objects.  Change these lines:

```
x='wal mart'
y='wall mart'
```

To:

```
x=u'wal mart'
y=u'wall mart'
```

If you will be working with `str` objects, then you can convert them to `unicode` objects using the `unicode()` constructor:

```
x='wal mart'
y='wall mart'

dm(unicode(x)) == dm(unicode(y))
```

Comment: There it is thanks! I was trying x="u'wal mart'" which was incorrect

Answer (score 3):

```
a = u'katherine'
b = u'catherine'

dm(a) == dm(b)
```